# Any way to programatically set auto refresh on a report in a ReportViewer?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I know you can set the auto refresh interval in the design of the report itself, but what I am trying to do is allow a user to set/change this interval himself in a web app (ASP.NET) that uses a ReportViewer control. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are serving the report via a page, you could use the simple HTTP Meta tag to refresh the page. [META REFRESH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)